# How do I access the private IP?

Tags: networking

I am in a college that employs private IP addressing scheme. Different parts of the college have been allotted separate private IPs. Is it possible that I can access the private IP of other parts of the college. Manually setting the IP results in no connection. Also I am using an HTTP proxy. Any help ?

Comment: Questions about School/Business networks you don't control are generally off-topic for SU.  Unless you can provide SIGNIFCANTLY more technical information about how it's configured, end to end, there's not much we can tell you.   Your best bet it to talk to the school's IT staff about what you'd like to accomplish.

Comment: Well the IP range which I wanna access is 172.31.108.*. I have been allotted 172.31.80.*. Both IPs have been allocated different proxies for internet connection. My proxy becomes extremely slow at night whereas that of the aforementioned is reasonably fast. Also if any of the system is up with that particular IP, I can ssh into that.

Comment: **is it possible that I can access the private IP of other parts of the college.* - You have to tell us, if the network been configured, to allow this or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am in a college that employs private IP addressing scheme.

You can read [Address Allocation for Private Internets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) for more detail about this;
roughly summarized, they are in one of the following ranges:

- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
- 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
- 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255

> Different parts of the college have been allotted separate private IPs.

This can be done by the means of

- [subnetwork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) (separates the addresses)
- [virtual LANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN) (separates the physical traffic)

> Is it possible that I can access the private IP of other parts of the college.

This depends on how the subnetworks, VLANs and routing is set up in your gateway.

> Manually setting the IP results in no connection. Also I am using an HTTP proxy. Any help ?

The IP needs to be within one of the subnetworks of the VLANs on the interface of your gateway that is provided with a connection; if you don't know what this is and don't want DHCP, you should contact your network administrator or attempt to figure this out further.

> Well the IP range which I wanna access is 172.31.108.*. I have been allotted 172.31.80.*. Both IPs have been allocated different proxies for internet connection. My proxy becomes extremely slow at night whereas that of the aforementioned is reasonably fast.

Sounds like a dorm situation. Well, if you try to set a 172.31.108.x IP but your gateway is configured for 172.31.80.x it simply won't work because it is not configured to do something with source traffic from 172.31.108.x. In more technical terms, this means that 172.31.108.x is not in the subnetwork mask of the 172.31.80.x interface and/or there is no correct routing table entry.

Being able to connect TO 172.31.108.x does not mean you can connect FROM 172.31.108.x. This is the exact same idea that you and I can visit Super User just fine but we cannot be in the LAN of Super User unless we physically connect (or VPN) ourselves to the gateway in the server room of Stack Exchange OR if the network administrator explicitly sets up the required magic to do it remotely.

**TL;DR:** Tell your network admin that it is slow, exercising his responsibility to fix it. If the machines and links are similar; someone on the network might be hogging it, or a machine or link is defective.

Comment: Well, the gateway is different for both IPs. For 80.*, it's 80.1 and for 108.*, it's 108.1.

Comment: Does not matter.  The solution is the same.  Tell somebody who can actually fix it, to fix it, then wait for them to fix it.

Comment: Well, even if I manually set a route to get to that other subnet, the packets may get there (unless there's a firewall rule that stops it). Unfortunately, the response will never get back to me because the device on the other side doesn't have a route back to my subnet. Am I assuming correctly ?

Comment: Assuming your gateway is the only device connecting your subnet to that other subnet, you are not able to change from the default routing. You either route your packets to go through your gateway or your packets won't get to the other subnet at all. -- Note that the route table is used to determine the next hop your packet goes to based on the destination IP. For your device, the next hop is your gateway. For your gateway, in a dorm, the next hop is likely the gateway of the other subnetwork. -- By default most firewalls block anything that happens differently from how it is supposed to happen